# XSLT to select the required data

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to select the data from the "wd:EFW2_Year_End_Submitter_Data" node from the following XML:

```css
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <wd:Get_EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing_Data_Response
            xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
            wd:version="v27.2">
            <wd:Request_Criteria>
                <wd:Company_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">74b0eaa34f93109eb7ee051fc8a981b2</wd:ID>
                </wd:Company_Reference>
                <wd:Calendar_Year_Reference>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f9adeb241f021000180055333a6b00be</wd:ID>
                    <wd:ID wd:type="Calendar_Year_ID">2016</wd:ID>
                </wd:Calendar_Year_Reference>
                <wd:Exclude_Opt_Out_Workers>1</wd:Exclude_Opt_Out_Workers>
            </wd:Request_Criteria>
            <wd:Response_Data>
                <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing>
                    <wd:Company_Reference>
                        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">74b0eaa34f93109eb7ee051fc8a981b2</wd:ID>
                    </wd:Company_Reference>
                    <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing_Data>
                        <wd:Calendar_Year_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">f9adeb241f021000180055333a6b00be</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Calendar_Year_ID">2016</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Calendar_Year_Reference>
                        <wd:EIN>746000203</wd:EIN>
                        <wd:Kind_of_Employer_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">82014e83bea2415fb8ce52a8459c6c4b</wd:ID>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Kind_of_Employer_ID">None apply</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Kind_of_Employer_Reference>
                        <wd:Third_Party_Sick_Pay_Indicator>1</wd:Third_Party_Sick_Pay_Indicator>
                        <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Submitter_Data>
                            <wd:EIN>746000203</wd:EIN>
                        </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Submitter_Data>
                        <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Box_Data>
                            <wd:Box_Description>Dependent care benefits</wd:Box_Description>
                            <wd:Amount>2229162.52</wd:Amount>
                        </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Box_Data>
                        <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Box_Data>
                            <wd:Box_Description>Federal income tax withheld</wd:Box_Description>
                            <wd:Amount>134782324.03</wd:Amount>
                        </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Box_Data>
                        <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Box_Data>
                            <wd:Box_Description>Medicare tax withheld</wd:Box_Description>
                            <wd:Amount>13689167.58</wd:Amount>
                        </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Box_Data>
                    </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing_Data>
                </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing>
            </wd:Response_Data>
        </wd:Get_EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing_Data_Response>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Can any one help me in providing the xpath that i need to mention in XSLT. I'm using the following XSLT to get the data from 'wd:EFW2_Year_End_Submitter_Data', however, i'm not able to retrieve the required data.

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" 
    xmlns:etv="urn.com.workday/etv" 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:this="urn:I00179.xsl">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="NEWLINE" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="SINGLESPACE">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>    
    
    <xsl:variable name="Direction_Left"><xsl:text>LEFT</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Direction_Right"><xsl:text>RIGHT</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Record_Identifier"><xsl:text>RA</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    
 
     <xsl:template match="wd:Get_EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing_Data_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing/wd:EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing_Data"> 
    
        <xsl:value-of select="$Record_Identifier"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:EFW2_Year_End_Submitter_Data/wd:EIN"/>
        
            
        <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>
            
        
        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank You !

Comment: _For the following XPATH all data is getting selected_ - Are you sure?? What you're probably seeing is the the result of XSLTs built-in templates, but it's impossible to say for sure since you haven't given us enough information to reproduce the issue. (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your template matches nothing, because `wd:Get_EFW2_Year_End_Employer_Filing_Data_Response` is not the root element. Note that there is a difference between *matching* and *selecting*. It's not at all clear what your question is about. What is the result you expect to get in the given example?

Comment: modified the question. Can you have look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Michael, You correct. My template matches nothing. I modified the xpath and i'm able to get the required data. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

How about `//wd:City`? Give more details if you want a better answer.

Comment: modified the question. Can you have look at it. Thanks.